# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdfminer.high_level'

Tags: python, pdfminer

I work on project in pycharm , i'd like to use pdfminer in order to convert a pdf file to a text file.
My problem is when i run the app i't doesn't work and it display this error message : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdfminer.high_level'

```
import re
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages, extract_text

text = extract_text("_DarkWeb_1642453520.pdf")
print(text)
```

the full error message:

```
 /home/oran/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python /home/oran/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oran/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages, extract_text
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdfminer.high_level'
```

python version 3.10.4

Comment: You should always let people know what version of Python you are using at a mimimum. If I see a message like you got the first thing I would do is try to install the module.

Comment: hi , my python version is 3.10.4

Comment: I got this from another Stackoverflow question and it worked for me : 

"In order to use pdfminer.high_level, you will need to run pip3 install pdfminer.six. Then in order to use the package in your code, you will need to add the line import pdfminer.high_level after your import pdfminer line. This is because Python does not automatically import subpackages by default."

Answer (score 36):

I suppose that you installed only [**`pdfminer`**](https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer/) which is not maintained anymore.

To import the module [**`pdfminer.high_level`**](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/blob/master/pdfminer/high_level.py), you should go for [**`pdfminer.six`**](https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer.six/) instead by first running this command from your terminal :

```
pip install pdfminer.six
```

If you use a virtual environement, use the `dash` instead of the `dot`.

```
pip install pdfminer-six
```

Comment: hi , i already did that and got that message:
...
Requirement already satisfied: pdfminer.six in /home/oran/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin (20220524)
...

Comment: thank you all , i,m unistall pdfminer.six and then install it again.