# Python package in the wrong path leading to ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, linux, path, modulenotfounderror

I have found a few solutions here and elsewhere, but none of them has worked. Context: I am trying to get [pdf2txt](https://man.cx/pdf2txt) going on my Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS system. I am using Python 3.10.6, with no other versions present. The command-line states that it requires `python3-pdfminer` to work, which I installed with apt. Output states that there is no module named 'pdfminer.high_level'. This comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73831425/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pdfminer-high-level) notes that it's a part of [pdfminer.six](https://pdfminersix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which can be installed using pip, using a dash instead of a dot if it's inside a virtual environment.

```
$ python3 -m pip install pdfminer.six
```

states that requirements are already satisfied. To be sure, I also switched to a virtualenv and installed it there:

```
$ pip install pdfminer-six
```

Running `pdf2txt` in both cases results in the same error, i.e.

```
  File "/usr/bin/pdf2txt", line 9, in <module>
    import pdfminer.high_level
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdfminer.high_level'
```

I then tried to uninstall and reinstall `pdfminer.six`, first on the system wide version. `python3 -m pip uninstall pdfminer.six` (or just `pip3`) was not allowed, so I made a judgment of error and used sudo. Reinstalling now shows:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pdfminer.six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (-VERSION-)
```

so I am not sure if it is properly installed. So I tried in the virtualenv where there were no problems. But the same error remains.

I reinstalled `python3-pdfminer` but without success.

In the virtualenv, I found:

```
./lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdfminer/high_level.py
./lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdfminer/__pycache__/high_level.cpython-310.pyc
```

I then created a test Python file that imports `pdfminer.high_level` and ran it, with no problem. I then did the same outside the virtualenv. `pdfminer` is imported correctly, but it can't import `pdfminer.high_level`. So I found the following:

- When I uninstall `pdfminer.six`, it looks in `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages` and removes it from there.
- When I install `pdfminer.six`, it looks in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`. Here, the `high_level` package is present. But the system always looks in `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages`, so the package is never found.

So, I think that I found the cause of the problem. Running `pdf2txt` doesn't work in the virtualenv because it's still a file in `/usr/bin` that will look for a system-wide version. I suppose that I can update a system environment path to point to `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`, and solve it like this (`pdf2txt` is actually not binary so I can append to `sys.path`). But why has this discrepancy occurred in the first place? And what is the proper way to deal with it? After all, there is a reason why some packages are installed in different locations.

Many thanks.

EDIT: Adding to sys.path doesn't work, but adding to PYTHONPATH does. Not sure if this is something that I should watch out for in the future, or just a result of a Python executable installed in /usr/bin messing up with the idea of using a virtualenv in the first place.

Comment: Yes and thanks, but only in the sense of what I already knew, i.e. how to add to sys.path (not working in my case) or PYTHONPATH (works). It doesn't answer my question on why it happens in the first place, but I guess that's fine, I just needed to learn about what to look out for in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this issue happens when you have same name file in your working dir. So please check that first like if you have a file name "pdfminer.py".
If that is not the case then I usually try the previous version of lib.
you can try installing previous version with

`pip install pdfminer.six==20220506`

Comment: Not relevant in my case, but thanks for the suggestion (definitely appropriate in some circumstances). See edit in OP.